# Roles in Spiral Methodology

Tags: roles

What are the Roles in the Spiral Methodology approach?

For example Scrum only has three roles 'scrum master', 'the team' and 'product owner'

Comment: scrum has more roles, but the roles you mention are the 'pigs'... the other roles are called chickens and not committed to the project.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that [Spiral Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiral_model) has (should have) any explicit roles. It's a methodology, not a framework. While Scum is a framework, like RUP, MSF, PRINCE2, etc.